# Animation when user go into site, but not when he travels

Tags: animation, onload

I have a website, where i wanna use some simple animations when the page is loaded. The animation code is not a problem. This animation is some fading in of menu and other elements. I will call this an intro of my page. I want the end-user to see this animation ONLY when he visit a site, and dont see when he clicks some links in menu and travel around my website. I worked it out for now by putting the animation code only on fron page, but for example: what if someone gives a link to mywebsite.com/news to someone. He will go into site and he will not see the animation cause its only on the front page. Any solutions? I think about some session & cookies "if" statements with php maybe, but I'm a begginer and I dont know how to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Make your home page always the same, and just load the code of the other pages. I mean, you can use frames, or php code with include('file.php'); for example. Then your animation will be always on the same page, or just load a frame in every page of your site, and the anim in that frame.

Comment: Loading a php file is irrelevant: that's all on the server before it goes to the client. Putting the content in frames is possible, but can get messy - it's hard to provide links to the separate pages conveniently, and may confuse the user if they want to print off any of the site. So I don't support these suggestions.

Comment: I agree with Colin Fine. I want links to work fine. Btw, this site is a Drupal 6 template. I've tried with some drupal modules but nothing suits my needs. Maybe u know some. This question is a trouble everywhere I ask...

Comment: I don't recommend you the cookies, because a lot of people use to turn them off in the explorer. But, if you are working with a server face language, sessions can be a good work. You can check if the session is active (so the user has seen the anim), or not (first time user, you can show your anim).

Answer (score 0):

You are asking your system (as a whole) to remember information between HTTP requests (page fetches). HTTP is by design a stateless system, so you will have to use one of the mechanisms which have been developed for remembering information: cookies or (server-side) sessions. (Actually, sessions are usually implemented using cookies, but you can think of them as separate technologies).

Sessions in PHP are quite easy to use: you'll just fire the animation when you create a new session. But you will have to work out how you are going to decide when a session is continuing, and when it has expired and you need a new one.

Comment: Ok, I've made some steps thanks to You. But is there a way to kill session when the user leave the site? Im trying to find a way to do this on the internet, but it seems thats very hard to achieve

Comment: What does "leave the site" mean? When they navigate away from your site? But what if they have another tab open on your site - have they left it? That's what I meant by "you will have to work out how you ... decide when a session ... has expired".

Answer (score 0):

To destroy one php session you can do `session_destroy();`

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but how to destroy it when user close the site? If he close browser or when he close some in-browser tab? Is it possible to catch this event?

Comment: Yes, you capture the onClose() event of the window, and then try to make an ajax script to a php that destroys the sesion.